# How to configure Multi-tenant plugin as single-tenant with Spring security plugin as resolver?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, multi-tenant

I can create a secure, multi-tenant web app with Grails by :

- setup spring security plugin,
- setup Multi-tenant plugin (via multi-tenant install and multi-tenant-spring-security)
- update config.groovy :

  tenant {
    mode = "multiTenant"
    resolver.type = "springSecurity"
  }
- add : Integer userTenntId in User domain
- add a domain class for tenant Organization
- associate the tenants with Organization
- Edit BootStrap.groovy.

Everything works fine in multi-tenant mode, but how to use mode = "singleTenant" ?
This configuration sound not working :

tenant {
  mode = "singleTenant"
  resolver.type = "springSecurity"
}

---

Edit :

I try this config :

```
tenant {
  mode = "singleTenant"
  resolver.type = "springSecurity"
  datasourceResolver.type = "config"

  dataSourceTenantMap {
    t1 = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:custFoo"
    t2 = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:custBar"
  }
}
```

But I get :

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Executing action [list] of controller [org.example.TicketController]  caused exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

and :

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.grails.multitenant.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCurrentTenant.getTenantIdFromSpringSecurity(SpringSecurityCurrentTenant.groovy:50)
    at org.grails.multitenant.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCurrentTenant.this$2$getTenantIdFromSpringSecurity(SpringSecurityCurrentTenant.groovy)
    at org.grails.multitenant.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCurrentTenant$this$2$getTenantIdFromSpringSecurity.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.multitenant.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCurrentTenant.get(SpringSecurityCurrentTenant.groovy:41)
    at com.infusion.tenant.spring.TenantBeanContainer.getBean(TenantBeanContainer.java:53)
    at com.infusion.tenant.spring.TenantMethodInterceptor.invoke(TenantMethodInterceptor.java:32)
    at $Proxy14.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still testing the multi tenant plugin (core) in singleTenant mode but it's already running altho not tested throughlly.

Here are the steps:

**1-** install ***spring security plugin***, run *grails s2-quickstart* to set up the roles

**2-** Install ***multi-tenant-ehcache plugin*** and change your cache.provider_class in Datasource.groovy to:

**cache.provider_class = 'grails.plugin.multitenant.ehcache.cache.MultiTenantEhCacheProvider'**

**3-** *Install multi tenant (core) plugin* and set up the datasource resolver plus the dns resolver i did it in a static way. Plus altho in the plugin doc says we can configure the *dataSoruceTenantMap* like this:

dataSourceTenantMap {

- t1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ets_dev1"
- t2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ets_dev2"

}
 
didnt worked for me so i used the jndi option through *grails.naming.entries* in the config:

/** **Config.groovy** **/

***grails.naming.entries*** = [ 
    "jdbc/lh_dev1": [ 
        type: "javax.sql.DataSource",
 
        auth: "Container",
        description: "My data source", 
        driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lh_dev1", 
        username: "xxx",
 
        password: "xxx",
 
        maxActive: "100", 
        maxIdle: "30",
 
        maxWait: "10000" 
    ],
        "jdbc/lh_dev2": [
                type: "javax.sql.DataSource",
                auth: "Container",
                description: "My data source",
                driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lh_dev2",
                username: "xxx",
                password: "xxx",
                maxActive: "100",
                maxIdle: "30",
                maxWait: "10000"
        ] 
]

//MultiTenant plugin configuration 
 
tenant{

```
    mode = "singleTenant" // "singleTenant" OR "multiTenant"
    datasourceResolver.type = "config" //This is the default and can be omitted

    dataSourceTenantMap { 
        **t1 = "java:comp/env/jdbc/lh_dev1"****
        **t2 = "java:comp/env/jdbc/lh_dev2"**
    }

    resolver.request.dns.type = "config"  //This is the default
            domainTenantMap {
                      lh_dev1 = 1
                      lh_dev2 = 2

            }
    }
```

At this point you will have 2 domains linked with 2 diferent databases once u click for example:

- http://lh_dev1:8080/myProject --> it will open your project db
  lh_dev1
- http://lh_dev2:8080/myProject --> it will open your project db
  lh_dev2

each tenant (client) has his own database.

**4-** Install ***multi-tenant-spring-security plugin*** and follow this steps(note i didnt implemented the security plugin yet once i do i will post the results):

In *Config.groovy*, your tenant resolver property should look like this:

```
tenant{ 
 resolver.type = "springSecurity"
}
```

You will also need to add the following field to your Spring-Security User Domain Class

Integer userTenantId

**Final Issues -->**

Every time we fire up grails he will only do a create/update on the default database all the others will remain clean since i still dont know how to solve this problem so i simple exported the default database structure to all my other tenants database.

Finally i didnt do the @MultiTenant Annoation on the domains because i'm working with diferent database didnt saw the point of injecting the tenantid since every db has his own personal records.